# JAX-RS, with JAXB @XmlTransient

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I am developing a RESTful service using JAX-RS and JAXB. I have a `Complain` class, following is a striped down version of it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "complain")
@XmlRootElement
public class Complain implements Serializable {

  private String title;
  private String description;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "complainidComplain")
   private Collection<Comment> commentCollection;

   @XmlTransient
   public Collection<Comment> getCommentCollection() {
     return commentCollection;
   }
}
```

Note: I have decorated `getCommentCollection` with `@XmlTransient` annotation, because I don't want to see comment when I'm looking for all the complains at `@Path("/")`.

**example.com/api/complain/**

```
<complains>
 <complain>
  <title>Foo</title>
  <description>Foo is foo</description>
 </complain>
 <complain>
  <title>Bar </title>
  <description>Bar is bar</description>
 </complain>
</complains>
```

But when I'm looking for a specific `Complain` at `@Path("/{id}")`, I need the comments to appear in the XML output.

**example.com/api/complain/1**

```
<complain>
 <title>Foo</title>
 <description>Foo is foo</description>
 <comments>
  <comment> Yes, i agree </comment>
  <comment> Lorem if foo </comment>
 </comments>
</complain>
```

Since I have decorated `getCommentCollection` with `@XmlTransient` annotation I can't get comments when I'm looking for a specific `Complain` at `@Path("/{id}")`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Annotating with ```@XmlTransient``` is a compile-time decission so you can't change it dynamically on runtime. You could map to a limited view (either by a second class or setting commentCollection to null) or take a look at the solutions discussed at [How to conditionally serialize with JAXB or Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941398).

Comment: @lefloh , I would be thankfull if you can show me how to map to a limited view, I'm new to JAX-RS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotating with `@XmlTransient` is a compile-time decission so you can't change it dynamically on runtime. As discussed at [How to conditionally serialize with JAXB or Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941398) you could use [Jacksons JsonView](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) or [MOXy's external mapping-files](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html).

If you don't want to change your Serializer you could map `Complain` to a limited Class like e.g. `ComplainPreview` which has only the properties `title` and `description`. You could also simply set `commentCollection` to `null` before returning it in your JAX-RS resource method.

Last (and maybe cleanest) solution: Fetch only the data you want to return from the Database. Therefore you need different queries for your two use cases. You could for instance use a [Constructor Expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) for the first one:

```
select new com.yourcompany.Complain(c.title, c.description) from Complain c
```

Don't forget to add the correspondent Constructor.